# Show that the system has the form $u' = Au$, where A is $\omega-periodic$ for all $\omega > 0$

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

The system is given by $u_1' = 2u_1, u_2' = u_1 + 3u_2$

Now I have not done this before, but I have $u_1 = Ae^{2x}$ and $$u_2 = \exp(-3(x-x_0))[y_0-\exp(2x_0)\frac{A}{5}] + u_1/5$$ through using the integrating factor method.

I have used some initial condition to solve the equation $u_2' - 3u_2 = Ae^{2x}$

Now, I must be honest, I am pretty stumped. How do I form this matrix?

The fact that it is periodic for all omega makes me think it is a constant matrix.

Comment: It seems like you might be confusing $A$s here. The $A$ in the title is a matrix, but the $A$ in $u_1=Ae^{2x}$ is a scalar. It’s also not entirely clear to me what you’re asking. Finding the matrix $A$ doesn’t require solving the system—it can be written down directly from the given system of equations. If you’re trying to find a solution to the system in matrix form, that’s another matter.

Comment: Ahh I have used A as a constant in the body of the question

Comment: So, do you simply need to express the system as a matrix equation, or do you actually want to solve it? The title of your question suggests to me the former.